# Cython: extending Python standard library classes

Tags: cython

I am very new to Cyhon and have very little experience with C, but I am testing Cython by refactoring an existing module I wrote.

I am not sure how I should extend a Python standard library class. this:

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator

cdef class MyCtxManager(ContextDecorator):
    # override methods
```

gives me an error:

```
'ContextDecorator' is not a type name
```

How do I extend ContextDecorator into a Cython class?

Comment: You cannot use a python class as base for a cdef-class, as far as I know

Comment: You could of course remove the cdef bit and just write a normal python class in your cython file. If the goal is to speed up a python class via cython that's totally a valid thing to do.

Comment: @ead that is not what I am observing. The snippet in my OP (replacing the comment with a `pass` statement) gives me the same error when entered in an iPython console.

Comment: @ngoldbaum I'd like to type the class members, so `cdef class` is the only way I know to do that.

Comment: @ead Sorry, totally misread your comment. So how do I go about typing a class members if I am inheriting from an external library? That would only allow me to use a pure-Python version of my Cython module, which *may* speed up things but maybe not enough worth the refactoring.

Comment: Composition might be the right approach here. Which isn’t a bad thing, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Or create a Cython class holding your typed members, then a second normal class that inherits from both the typed class and the Python class?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the two comments above. Does somebody mind to write an answer that I can choose? Thanks.